# SAML implementation for realizing user-login

Tags: java, oauth, salesforce, saml, onelogin

I'm developing a web service for integrating with Salesforce and I have my own user-registration/login mechanism in the service.

I'd like to implement both OAuth and SAML login for unregistered users.

Currently I've developed the OAuth one which user can leverage to authorize my service for accessing user's Salesforce resources, and after authorization one mapping user account would be registered automatically in my service. Then user can access my service as a logged-in user and my service is able to access the user's resources in Salesforce with user's "access token" retrieved with OAuth.

But in SAML, I'm really confused that if there is any part like the "access token" for SAML that I could possess for future resources access? In the document of salesforce, it mentioned "Federated authentication using Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) allows you to send authentication and authorization data between affiliated but unrelated Web services. This enables you to sign on to Salesforce from a client application."

In my scenario, the SP is Salesforce, and the IdP might be OneLogin, my service plays the role of client application. Sorry that I cannot describe more details since I'm not quite sure about what to do with SAML to realize the same mechanism as I did with OAuth. Does there anyone have the same problem or just solved problems alike? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a SAML page to your application would essentially operate as a replacement/alternate for your current log-in page.

Instead of taking a Username/password the SAML page would accept a signed SAML assertion from an IdP and part of the assertion would be the username.

So rather than a unique set of oAUTH credentials per user (which is what it sounds like you're doing currently with Salesforce) the SAML set up lets the IdP 'vouch' for the identity of any user.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi J. Offenhartz, thank you for your reply and I've leveraged the toolkit of OneLogin and able to login Saleforce via OneLogin SAML authentication. After the SSO procedure the page would be redirected to Salesforce, but I still need to access files in Salesforce by my service. I'm really confused how can I keep staying in my service page after SSO and able to get resource from Salesforce just like I did by OAuth. Is SAML response the 'vouch' you mentioned in your reply? Should I take it as some kind of passcode each time I access files in Salesforce?

Comment: I'm trying to follow the "OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion Flow" to get "access_token" from Salesforce and see if this could solve my problem.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this API: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/saml-assertions/generate-saml-assertion ?

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the Salesforce API - but if their endpoint can accept a SAML assertion, you can use this API to generate oAuth credentials and then cache them on a per-user basis.

It will, however, require that you collect a username/password (and potentially MFA) which is a bit of a pain point for users - which is why I recommend caching this info

Comment: I appreciate for your keeping concern on this case, J. Offenhartz. I noticed a page on Salesforce which could retrieve "access_token" from the response assertion: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm
I'm trying to follow the steps and implement. But I don't know how to redirect to my service with the response assertion which OneLogin send to the assertion consumer service URL at Salesforce. After authentication, the assertion just passed to and consumed by Salesforce.